# Change the shape of jcrop selection

Tags: buddypress, jcrop

I'm working with jcrop inside of BuddyPress and I was wondering how I could go about setting a different selection shape from a square to either a circle or hexagon with a set aspect ratio to meet the profile picture shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ability to crop circles or hexagons - this is a cropper limitation.
BuddyPress Avatar Cropper uses WordPress wp_get_image_editor(). So this can't be changed at this time and WordPress doesn't have ability to crop anything except squares or rectangles.

All the corresponding code is in `/buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php`. See line 550 for BuddyPress 1.7.

Comment: I wanted to add to this that I found a tidbit of a workaround to get the desired effect I wanted. I've adjusted the crop view to meet shape the avatar is in.
`#avatar-crop-pane { border-radius: 50%; }`
So now when cropping with a square the user will see their avatar to the right in a circle instead.